# Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly slow when alternating tasks

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, graphics

I started to use Ubuntu 20.04 as my main O.S and I am facing a bit of a trouble. I am currently with a Dual Boot with Windows, and while my Windows 10 is installed on my SSD, my Ubuntu is installed on my HD Sata, so I wonder if this lag behaviour could be explained due to the fact of the installation on the HD, but I really doubt it.

When I am normally using my computer, after a while since I boot it (navigating in the web, using apps such as Discord, Teams, IDEs (Sublime Text, Atom)...), changing between tabs and tasks gets slow. For example, if I am writing a piece of code in Atom and want to browse something in Firefox, the alt tab takes ~ 2 seconds. If I am watching a stream on Twitch and want to go to my terminal, when I click to open the terminal, the browser freezes for 1 or 2 seconds and then my terminal is opened.

I already searched for a solution and one that works temporarily is changing between the NVIDIA DRIVERS on the Additional Drivers app.

[Additional Drivers APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohZcY.png)

Basically if this laggy behaviour starts, I can change between the latest tested driver and the open-source one and it will temporarily solve my problem. But if everytime I get this problem I have to change between the drivers, I will never fully solve my problem.

I saw other trends saying that it can be fixed by changing some options on Power Management in the BIOS, but I haven't tried that yet.

My Ubuntu is fully updated and so are the other apps.

I don't think that it is necessary, but my computer configs are: i7-7700, 16gb RAM 2133Mhz, B-150M Gigabyte Gaming Motherboard, 550W, NVIDIA 1650Super, 128GB SSD, 1TB Sata 3 HD.

What can I do prevent this trouble to happen?

--UPDATE--
While task switching from Firefox I found a high CPU usage from Xorg and don't know the cause or how to solve it. I also noticed that when alt-tabbing sometimes Firefox uses up to 50% of CPU. I usually have up to 10 open tabs.
[High CPU Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybiuP.png)

Comment: The HDD is indeed the bottleneck. Were the other way around you would be experiencing even worse performance with any modern Windows. The switchroo you think "temporarily solves the problem" is likely an illusion.

Comment: Could you check whether the swap memory is starting to be used when the slowness starts? `free` gives you this information. Still, that would not explain a delay of 2 seconds to switch tab, and with 16 GB RAM, you already need to do efforts to kick swap into action. When slowness is there, also watch the output of `top` to see CPU use and identify processes using it. Perhaps a memory leak with the NVIDIA drivers? Installing also Ubuntu on the SSD would make a significant difference in perceived performance (but again, that does not explain your current slowness).

Comment: @vanadium I did what you said and found high CPU usage from Xorg and gnome shell. I'll post a picture in the main question. I also noticed that the lag is happening only when switching to or back to Firefox. I'll try to reinstall Firefox and see if this solves my problem. Otherwise, do you suggest anything else? Should I report this high CPU usage?

Comment: I guess this is related to the graphics driver. Perhaps test if it happens when you turn hardware acceleration off in Firefox. Settings - uncheck "Use recommended performance settings" then uncheck the setting for hardware acc that appears.